# Grab full html source and bypass <noscript>

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, get, browser, webrequest

Ok, so I am trying to make a youtube downloader with mp3 converter

There is this awesome site that does it for me...

I can send the link and it processes the information...

However when I am about to download using the source (extracting link), it just gives me

```
<noscript>
<div class="warning">You have to enable JavaScript to use this Service!</div>
```

And the link is not present

If i use chrome, the source is:

```
<div id="dl_link" style="display: block; "> <a href="/get?video_id=UA8rcLvS1BY&amp;h=8a4dfe7979a47aae13e47dad3999d09e"> <b>Download</b></a> · <a href="#" onclick="showLinkBox(); return false;">Link this mp3</a></div>
```

How do I get it and download it without the user clicking anything!

Answer (score 0):

Guess number one: Their site uses the request headers to figure out if the browser you're using supports javascript...

Try setting the [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) http header to mimic a suitable browser when you make your request and see if they respond with the correct response.

**Update**
Since guess one was wide of the mark, more information is required, I'd suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to work out what is being sent back and forth between your browser and their service, and try to reproduce this behaviour in your code.

Comment: I have tried that: it still doesn't show the download link in the source... Here is the code:

     If stringyt.Contains("&") Then
                Dim final As String = stringyt.Substring(0, stringyt.IndexOf("&"))
                WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/?c#v=" + final, "_self", Nothing, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7")
            Else
             
            End If

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: but that is not the problem. The webpage SHOWS the javascript fine (with download link). IT is when I try to get the webpage source that the problem occurs. Instead of where it should have the dl link it says sorry you need a javascript enabled browser. If I just pressed download it works. Is it a problem with the way I am grabbing the source (Webbrowser1.documenttext.tostring)?

Answer (score 0):

[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) seems to support it. Try calling that with `Process.Start` ?